# systemd in Raspbian for NZBGet

Tags: systemd, raspbian

Having shifted to `systemd` I am having to run software such as NZBGet, Sonarr and from `/etc/systemd/system` folder. I have managed to get all but NZBGet running here is the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=NZBGet
After=network.target

[Service]
User=osmc
Group=osmc
ExecStart=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -D
ExecStop=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -Q
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process

[Install]
# Needed to run nzbget at boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I enable the service via `sudo systemctl enable nzbget` and reboot, check the status with `sudo systemctl status` I get the following message:

```
osmc@osmc:~$ sudo systemctl status nzbget
● nzbget.service - NZBGet
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nzbget.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2015-07-05 08:52:01 BST; 2h 16min ago
Process: 302 ExecStop=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -Q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 240 ExecStart=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -D (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 240 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 05 08:52:01 osmc nzbget[302]: Unable to send request to nzbget-server at 127.0.0.1 (port 6789)
```

I cannot access the webui either as the service isn't running. I cannot figure out why the service isn't running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `nzbget -D` runs it in the background as a daemon you need to tell systemd
this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -D
# process will demonize and parent return ok
Type=forking
```

or perhaps not run with `-D`?

See this [article](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html). It is one in a series on systemd that I can highly recommend.

Comment: That worked like a charm! May I ask why? I'm keen to learn.

Comment: Like many people with systemd, I intuit by example. This was the [article](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html) I used. It is one in a series on systemd that I can highly recommend.

Comment: systemd.service(5) documents the possible values of the Type directive.